# String Matching - Character Weight

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I am doing a small research where i look for string matching algorithms and implements them in order to compare some of the previous ones with a new novel algorithm that have been published recently in which the author states that it performs better than Boyer Moore algorithm.

My questions is not coding but more of understanding what does the term "character weight" means, here is quote from the paper:

[image]

I have read all the paper but the term is not defined anywhere, i have read other papers regarding the same subject and i can't anything that help no what does this term means. I have already emailed the authors but i am still waiting for a reply.

Maybe does it mean ASCII code or .... ?

Here is a reference to the paper:
[IEEE Paper - Exact anD Like String Matching (ELSM)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6618726)

Update:

I found it weird that the authors didn't specify either Time nor Space complexity but they did mention this

> "The search time is found to be constant regardless of the length of the search pattern. The performance of ELSM is very high compared with the most two famous algorithms BM and Brute force. The time consumed is about 6%, in average, of
>   the time consumed in the two mentioned algorithms."
>
> "The experimental results reveal that the novel algorithm appears more efficient than BM many times in worst case, and the longer the pattern, the bigger the performance improvement"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an abstract algorithm and not programming. It would be better to ask this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does the author state in what way it performs better? Time? Space? Quality?

Comment: I updated the questions with an answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight of the character is an indication of its significance relative to other characters. For example, "g" might be given a weight of 100 and "e" a weight of 50.

The idea is the same as for a [weighted arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean). The weights to assign to characters is something you would have to decide.

Comment: Do you know this as a fact, or is this an opinion, as regards the algorithm the OP is discussing?

Comment: Assume that i choose the criteria and what you say is a fact, then for example you could say that the ASCII code for each character is it's weight since each ASCII is unique and is different from the other, right ?

Comment: @hatchet Unless the authors of the paper use a different definition, yes: [Weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting).

Comment: @user733659 No: if all characters have the same significance then their weights will be equal.

Comment: Weighting implies fuzzy matching, i.e. giving 'S' and 'Z' similar weights, but 'A' and 'Z' different weights. But the algorithm is comparing itself to Boyer Moore which finds a string in another string (not fuzzy). I was wondering if the author was using the term weighting to describe just summing the ASCII codes for instance. What I meant by my question above, is , are you familiar with this algorithm?

Comment: @hatchet No, I am not familiar with the algorithm. Note that if an algorithm incorporates weighting, it can be made into an unweighted algorithm by simply setting all the weights to be equal, whereupon, in this case, it would be fair to compare it to the Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is in the abstract:

> It is based on computing the sum of character's values in the search
>   string and comparing this sum with the sum of the values of the
>   corresponding characters in the sliding window. The sliding window
>   includes number of characters equals that of the search string and is
>   right shifted from the beginning and toward the end of the input
>   string.

This sounds very much like simply summing the ASCII values. I don't see how this is better than Boyer Moore though.